# SignalR (v.1.1.1) Call from Server

Tags: c#, signalr, .net-4.5, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using latest SignalR (v:1.1.1), and trying to simple call the Hub method periodically, every 3 seconds. I have seen many questions here and have duplicated the way, but `GetHubContext` method doesn't seem to be returning the correct instance of the class, so I can't call the methods of that class. You can duplicate the case with the following steps:

MyHub.cs:

```
 public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.triggerMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Global.asax:

```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
     while (true)
     {
       var myHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
       myHub.Clients.All.SendMessage("Hello World");
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
     }
   })
   .ContinueWith(t => { throw new Exception("The task threw an exception", t.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

I think this is as simple as it gets. I think this is correct way of doing it, but the debugger never hits `SendMessage` method. Does anyone know am I missing something very obvious? I am just trying to schedule a call to the SignalR client from the server for every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

On your Global.asax file, when you call 'myHub.Clients.All.SendMessage("Hello World")' it sends a message to the client, it does not call the SendMessage method in your class MyHub.

Please read [SignalR Documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr) to see some samples

Answer (score 1):

I ended changing the way the hub was created:

MyHostHub.cs

```
private readonly MyHost _host;
public MyHostHub(){ _host = new MyHost(); }
```

MyHost:

```
 private readonly static Lazy<IHubConnectionContext> _clients = new Lazy<IHubConnectionContext>(() => GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHostHub>().Clients);
 private IHubConnectionContext Clients
 {
    get { return _clients.Value; }
 }
 public void SendMessage(string message)
 {
    Clients.All.triggerMessage(message);
 }
```

My Global.asax:

```
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var myHost = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyHost>();
                myHost.SendMessage();
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        })
        .ContinueWith(t => { throw new Exception("The task threw an exception", t.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

This seems to be working just fine. Basically I moved out the code from the `Hub` class to another class that I can call in Global.asax but my hub has a reference for host.

Comment: Why bother with SendMessage() in the hub at all? just call `triggerMessage` from an instance of your hub within your loop in global.asax